# Must be possible to filter table names in a single database?

Tags: mysql-workbench

As far as I can tell, the search filter in the navigator will only search available database names, not table names.

If you click on a table name and start typing, it appears that a simple search can be performed beginning with the first letter of the tables.

I'm looking for way to be able to search all table names in a selected database. Sometimes there can be a lot of tables to sort through. It seems like a feature that would likely be there and I can't find it.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Found out the answer...

If you type for example `*.test_table` or the schema name instead of the asterisk it will filter them. The key is that the schema/database must be specified in the search query. The asterisk notation works with the table names as well. For example `*.*test*` will filter any table in any schema with test anywhere in the table name.

Comment: That's absolutely the most undiscoverable piece of functionality I've ever seen. Even to someone who's accustomed to writing SQL rather than clicking about a GUI it's hard to find.

Comment: if you wan to t search on the specific database you can also use this `YourDatabaseName.YourTableName` :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
SHOW TABLES like '%%';
```

To have it always in your tools, you can add it as a snippet to SQL aditions panel on the right.
Then you can always either bring it in your editor and type your search key between %%, or just execute it as it is (It will fetch all the tables of the database) and then just filter using the "filter rows" input of the result set.

Comment: That would be one way to do it, thanks, but just today I found out the answer I'm looking for.. If you type for example "*.test_table" or the schema name instead of the asterisk  it will filter them

Comment: That's a nice feature actually, thanks for the info. I noticed that it searches for tables in all open schemas which is also good in some cases

Comment: @groovenectar post your comment as a separate answer please as it is an actual answer to OPs question and works well. It will be more complete with your answer accepted to the question

Comment: @Evgenius, it was actually my question originally, but I've gone ahead and posted it as an answer